# Best method to make posts searchable, sortable and filterable - custom field, tag or category?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy

I'm wanting to create/modify either the existing post type, or create a new post type to be searchable, sortable and filterable by the following fields:

- Country from:
- Country to:
- Activity:

Ideally I would like them to be:

- Searchable, e.g. I could search for posts from Country X to Country Y with activity Z
- Listable, to be accessible via dropdown menus

What would be the best method of implementing this? A custom taxonomy?

Through hierarchical categories?
Using custom post data?

Thanks

Update:

I think the following is the best approach:

Custom post type that uses a custom taxonomy for each data point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

Custom post type for Deals:

Custom taxonomies for Countries and Activities, then a relational link between country from and country to as custom fields to the taxonomy :)